# Using JS to parse JSON Response

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

Apologies if my title is to vague, I will do my best to iterate.

I am using the following PHP Code to return a COUNT query from the MySQL DB.

The response is fine however I am having trouble parsing the response with JS as I want to present only the value within a dashboard (freeboard.io)

```
<?php 
//Create Database Connection
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","passwordROOT12");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect to the db brah: ' . mysql());
}

//Select the database
mysql_select_db("cp_investigations",$db);

//Replace the * in the query with the column names.
$result = mysql_query("select count(*) from emailAccount", $db);

//Create an array
$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $json_response[] = $row;


}
print json_encode($json_response);

//Close the db connection
fclose($db);
```

?>

**RESPONSE:**

[{"0":"49","count(*)":"49"}]

Here is the JS that I am currently using in attempt to have the value "49" reflect back into the dashboard.

```
datasources["Test"].0].
```

The problem is this is returning: **NaN** in the dashboard interface.

I'm quite certain I need to change this current JS so that It properly parses only the intended value. (However I have tried everything *I know* with no luck)

Comment: Parsing `var jsObj = JSON.parse(jsonText)` (some libraries like jQuery auto-parse responses) and using `jsObj[0]["0"] // -> "49"` or `jsObj[0]["count(*)"] // -> "49"` (depending upon which "49" was desired).

Comment: Hope the password in the code isn't your real password on a production server. If it is, you'll probably want to change it in your production code.

Comment: If anyone is reading this, THIS WAS DEFINITELY NOT! THE REAL PASSWORD FOR for my VPS which is located @161.12.211.23... T.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change that query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM emailAccount
```

This way, you will get "total" in your json to refer to. json.total

You are seeing 0 in the response because of  $json_response[] ... Adding [] is creating the first row of an array, which is the 0 key

Comment: So the issue is that the dashboard interface is not recognizing anything BUT the first "0" and wants to use this JS: 

datasources["EmailCount"].0].

How can I change the above JS to reference the new dictionary string? 

I thought it would be: 

datasources["EmailCount"].EmailCount].

Comment: You beauty! That was it, the array was causing the issue. 

Thanks Mate ~

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is replace this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select count(*) from emailAccount", $db);
```

with this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select count(*) as EmailCount from emailAccount", $db);
```

That should give you a better JSON response to work with (dictionary keys need to be strings).  Then you should be able to do something like this:

```
var myCount = datasources.EmailCount;
```

Comment: Many thanks for the "as" tip in the query that works great.

However *Holds Breath* For some reason the dashboard can only find reference to "0" as a dictionary key.

Screenshot here: http://tinypic.com/r/29gjs6x/8